# How to get margins after suest in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm running a sur with two equations using `suest`. How can I get the margins after `suest`?
For example:

```
eststo model1: reg y1 x1##(x2 x3)
eststo model2: reg y2 x1##(x2 x3)
suest model1 model2, vce(robust)

margins, dydx(x1) predict(equation(y1)) atmeans post
margins, dydx(x1) predict(equation(y2)) atmeans post
```

The `margins` does not work after `suest`. I'm using `suest` instead of `sureg` because I need robust standard errors.

Comment: In your example, `dydx(x1)` is just the coefficient of x1, it doesn't depend on the values of x2 or x3.

Comment: I just edited the example. I had the interaction terms in my regs, and need the marginal effects of x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, you only got the name of the equation wrong.

After `suest model1 model2`, the equations will be named `model1_mean` and `model2_mean`.

```
// Get some example data
webuse regress

// Generate y2
gen y2 = y + rnormal()

// Run regressions
reg y c.x1##c.(x2 x3)
estimates store M1
reg y2 c.x1##c.(x2 x3)
estimates store M2
suest M1 M2, vce(robust)

// Get partial effects on y with respect to x1 for each model at means of x2 and x3
margins, dydx(x1) predict(equation(M1_mean)) atmeans
margins, dydx(x1) predict(equation(M2_mean)) atmeans
```

Comment: When I run a -probit- model instead of OLS, the correct way is: "equation"_"depvar", like the following: margins, dydx(x1) predict(equation(M1_y)) atmeans